# Need a reference on period of LFSRs

Tags: reference-request

I need a reference for the fact that each LFSR with **XOR** operation has a period of $2^m-1$ excluding **zero state** and every LFSR with **XNOR** operations has the same period excluding **all ones state**.

I want to cite it when I'm writing about the usage of LFSR in a paper, I've found some references but they avoid a proof and all of them include only the case of XOR operations.

Since LFSRs are mostly used in signal processing I ask it here.

**Edit:**
I know that the feedback polynomial should be primitive.

Comment: L in LFSR means _Linear_ and so an LFSR with XNOR operation is, by definition, not an _L_ FSR but merely an FSR/ Also, as Nir Regev's answer points out, your "fact" for which you need a reference is not true.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I assume that the feedback polynomial is primitive, For XNOR operation I've found [Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp210.pdf), however I need a reference for it

Answer (score 3):

Not all LFSRs have the property of maximum cycle length. In fact, those who do have this property are based on a **primitive** polynomial of order n. It is a basic property of the extension field $GF(2^n)$ which is "spanned" by this primitive polynomial. The LFSR merely iterates through all of the powers of the polynomial primitive root.

Open a book on algebraic structures and cite the relevant part.

Comment: In all of the books I've found yet, Everything is proved for primitive LFSRs with XOR operations, I couldn't find a proof for XNOR. Xilinx suggests XNOR operations in its [documentation](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp210.pdf).

Comment: XOR + negation = XNOR. negation over GF(2) is + 1. i.e. over GF(2) XOR(a,b) = a+b and XNOR(a,b) = a+b+1 (remember that everything is modulo 2), so basically the all ones state negated will turn into the all zeros state which is not a valid state for LFSR. In any case, it'll not change the cycle period which will stay $2^n-1$

Comment: You are true. Do you think that this fact is somehow obvious and doesn't need any citations?

Comment: Thank you. Also it would be very nice if you mention a good reference book on the subject, I searched google books but most of the books didn't  have a robust proof.